# CodeMirror Highlight specific Regex-Match

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I'm trying to highlight all `%()%` substrings in the **`htmlmixed`** mode. The matching RegExp is `([%(](.*)[)%])`.

Here's the code i'm using for CodeMirror:

```js
const code = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector("#id"), {
     theme: "dracula",
     mode: "text/html",
     lineNumbers: true,
     firstLineNumber: 1,
     spellcheck: false,
     autocorrect: true,
     extraKeys: { "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete" },
     styleActiveLine: true,
     highlightSelectionMatches: { showToken: /\w/, annotateScrollbar: true }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? you can typically find the lexer for this file at `mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a style property in highlightSelectionMatches.

```
const code = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector("#id"), {
     theme: "dracula",
     mode: "text/html",
     lineNumbers: true,
     firstLineNumber: 1,
     spellcheck: false,
     autocorrect: true,
     extraKeys: { "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete" },
     styleActiveLine: true,
     highlightSelectionMatches: { 
          minChars: 2,
          showToken: /\w/,
          style:'matchhighlight',
          annotateScrollbar: true
    }
});
```

Add below in css:

```
.cm-matchhighlight {
  background: red !important
}
```